# AJAX Data with Dynamic form fields name

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ajaxform, jqueryform

Hello how can can make my ajax data call to be dynamic, I tried this

```
var opt_name = $(".NAME").data('opt_name');
    var opt_business = $(".BUSINESS").data('opt_business');
    var opt_phone = $(".PHONE").data('opt_phone');
    var opt_email = $(".EMAIL").data('opt_email');
    var opt_unique_name=$(".UNIQUE_NAME").data('opt_unique_name');
    
    var opt_name_val = $(".NAME")[key].value;
    var opt_business_val = $(".BUSINESS")[key].value;
    var opt_phone_val = $(".PHONE")[key].value;
    var opt_email_val = $(".EMAIL")[key].value;
    var opt_u_val = $(".U_VAL").data('opt_u_val');
    var opt_userid_val = $(".USER_ID_VAL").data('opt_user_id_val');
    var dataString = {'u': opt_u_val,
            'id': opt_userid_val,
            opt_email: opt_email_val,
            opt_name : opt_name_val,
            opt_phone : opt_phone_val,
            opt_business : opt_business_val,
            opt_unique_name : ''};
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'https://vative.us15.list-manage.com/subscribe/post',
      
        dataType: "json",
      data: dataString, // should be the same as below
      // data: {
        //     'u': '559dd913b49efd5f5515155bb',
        //     'id': '0985c209f3',
        //     'MERGE0': opt_email_val,
        //     'NAME' : 'Test 3',
        //     'PHONE' : '829121',
        //     'BUSINESS' : 'hskslas',
        //     'b_559dd913b49efd5f5515155bb_0985c209f3' : ''
        // },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log('Submitted');
        },
        
        error: function(data){
            console.log('Error');
          console.log(dataString);
        }
    });
}
 

});
```

I just want to get the field name since this field names always changes depending on the database or from embedded form.

The problem on my above code is that this will work.

```
data: {
             'u': '559dd913b49efd5f5515155bb',
             'id': '0985c209f3',
             'MERGE0': opt_email_val,
             'NAME' : 'Test 3',
             'PHONE' : '829121',
             'BUSINESS' : 'hskslas',
             'b_559dd913b49efd5f5515155bb_0985c209f3' : ''
         },
```

but not this

```
 data: {'u': opt_u_val,
            'id': opt_userid_val,
            opt_email: opt_email_val,
            opt_name : opt_name_val,
            opt_phone : opt_phone_val,
            opt_business : opt_business_val,
            opt_unique_name : ''};
```

Comment: You can use `$("#formid").serialize()` to get all the form fields.

Comment: @Barmar I can get all the form fields but my problem is that how to make the ajax data value also dymanic depending on the form field names

Comment: `data: $("#formid").serialize()`

Comment: In your above code you are succesfully making the values in your "dataString" object dynamic. But are you aware that the indices you are sending differ from the indices of the object you claim that works? Do you intend to make the indices dynamic as well?

Comment: @JuanChaher yes, I want to make it dynamic as well. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to generate dynamic keys inside your object, there is a very clean approach in the new ES2015 standard for JavaScript (formerly called ES6).

The syntax is the following:

```
var obj = {
  [myKey]: value,
}
```

So your code would look like this:

```
data: {'u': opt_u_val,
    'id': opt_userid_val,
    [opt_email]: opt_email_val,
    [opt_name]: opt_name_val,
    [opt_phone]: opt_phone_val,
    [opt_business]: opt_business_val,
    [opt_unique_name]: ''
};
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your goal is to have dynamic *keys* in your data object?

The reason your example isn't working is that instantiating an object uses the literal value of the keys (so basically a string), whereas what you want is the string value of the variable in the scope.

It's a bit messy to do, but I can think of two possibilities:

```js
data = {};
data[opt_email] = opt_email_val;
data[opt_phone] = opt_phone_val;
// and so on for each dynamic key to value
```

Alternatively the following *may* work (after transpilation depending on your targets), though I have not tried it:

```js
data = {
`${opt_email}`: opt_email_val,
`${opt_phone}`: opt_phone_val,
// and so forth
};
```

This second example works using the [Template literal syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) which will take the value of the variable and expand it into the string.

Comment: See Juan Chaher's answer above - much cleaner solution to this problem.

Comment: Thank you very much! You save me... It tooks me hours to fix this..

Comment: I'm glad I could help! Though I do recommend looking at the other answer to this for what is a syntactically cleaner solution to the problem.